# how to remove last single line available in file using perl

Tags: perl

how to remove last single line available in file using perl.

I have my data like below.

```
"A",1,-2,-1,-4,
"B",3,-5,-2.-5,
```

---

how to remove the last line... I am summing all the numbers but receiving a null value at the end.

Tried using chomp but did not work.

Here is the code currently being used:

```
while (<data>) {
    chomp(my @row = (split ',' , $_ , -1);
    say sum @row[1 .. $#row];
}
```

Comment: `chomp`? That makes no sense. You're using Text::CSV or Text::CSV_XS, right?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: while <data>{
chomp(my @row = (split ',' , data , -1);

  say sum @row[1 .. $#row];
}

Comment: [edit] that into you question please. And clarify your desired output -  you don't need to split at all if you want to drop the last _line_.

Comment: The code in your comment doesn't compile.

Comment: PS you have unbalanced parentheses

Answer (score 1):

Try this (shell one-liner) :

```
perl -lne '!eof() and print' file
```

or as part of a script :

```
while (defined($_ = readline ARGV)) {
    print $_ unless eof();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `Text::CSV` or `Text::CSV_XS` for handling comma separated value files.  Those modules are available on CPAN.  That type of solution would look like this:

```
use Text::CSV;
use List::Util qw(sum);

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({binary => 1})
    or die "Cannot use CSV: " . Text::CSV->error_diag;

while(my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
    next unless ($row->[0] || '') =~ m/\w/; # Reject rows that don't start with an identifier.
    my $sum = sum(@$row[1..$#$row]);
    print "$sum\n";
}
```

If you are stuck with a solution that doesn't use a proper CSV parser, then at least you'll need to add this to your existing while loop, immediately after your chomp:

```
next unless scalar(@row) && length $row[0]; # Skip empty rows.
```

The point to this line is to detect when a row is empty -- has no elements, or elements were empty after the chomp.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is an X/Y question. You think you want to avoid processing the final (empty?) line in your input when actually you should be ensuring that all of your input data is in the format you expect.

There are a number of things you can do to check the validity of your data.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use List::Util 'sum';
use Scalar::Util 'looks_like_number';

while (<DATA>) {
  # Chomp the input before splitting it.
  chomp;

  # Remove the -1 from your call to split().
  # This automatically removes any empty trailing fields.
  my @row = split /,/;

  # Skip lines that are empty.
  # 1/ Ensure there is data in @row.
  # 2/ Ensure at least one element in @row contains
  #    non-whitespace data.
  next unless @row and grep { /\S/ } @row;

  # Ensure that all of the data you pass to sum()
  # looks like numbers.
  say sum grep { looks_like_number $_ } @row[1 .. $#row];
}

__DATA__
"A",1.2,-1.5,4.2,1.4,

"B",2.6,-.50,-1.6,0.3,-1.3,
```